# R: slicing vectors by variable indices

Tags: r

I wonder why R acts weird when slicing a vector using variable indices. (I am trying to write a simple function to get moving averages.)
e.g.:

```
v <- c(1,2,3,4)
v[2:3] # works: [1] 2 3
i <-2
v[i:i+1] # gives "3" only
```

(I found the `filter()` solution.) I wonder if it is not allowed or there's something wrong how I used it. (RStudio 1.0.153, R 3.4.0)

Comment: Try `v[i:(i+1)]`

Comment: @d.b Thx! Haven't thought about the precedence (though I usually don't code in Python).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use parenthesis:

```
> v <- c(1,2,3,4)
> v[2:3] 
[1] 2 3
> i <-2
> v[i:(i+1)] 
[1] 2 3
> v[2:3] 
[1] 2 3
> i <-2
> v[i:(i+1)]
[1] 2 3
```